# how do i write the regex for a limited range repetition

Tags: regex, range

I am creating a form whereby the users can input a multi-value in a limited range
I am having trouble repeating the range as shown below, do i have to validate the comma as well and can i have the full regular expression solution for this?

I am allowing the user to input the value multiple times for a limited range of 0-1000 for 64 times or less

the input can be as follow:
1000,0,100,123,10,23,56,654,981

and here's my current regular expression for the range
(^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2}|1000)$)

Comment: I suggest you use some of your programming language features to divide-and-conquer. Even though you *may* be able to do this with one regex, it doesn't look like the best way forward. E.g., it doesn't look maintainable.

Answer (score 6):

#### Short answer:

```
^((1000|\d{1,3})(,|$)){1,64}
```

(Assuming you don't mind leading zeros. If you do, then change `\d{1,3}` to the more complex `([1-9][0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9]`.)

#### Long version:

We want to match (numbers in the range 0-1000) (repeated 1-64 times).

The first part can be done with `(1000|\d{3})` (with the caveat noted above about leading zeros).

For the second part, we use a handy trick to do the comma-separation aspect: we say that each number must *either* be followed by a comma *or* the end of the string.

Note that there is a small weakness to this approach: it accepts trailing commas, e.g. `1,2,3,` matches. If you're not okay, you can adapt by just adding, but it'll make the pattern longer:

```
^((1000|\d{1,3}),){0,63}(1000|\d{1,3})$
```

Note that I use an explicit `{0,63}` but many regex variants will accept the short form `{,63}` as well.

Also note that regex might not be the best solution for this - it might be better to just split the input string on commas and then iterate though the pieces, validating that each one is a number from 0-1000 and there are 64 or fewer pieces.

Comment: thanks so much, it works and validated perfectly
thanks for the description as well, very well explained :)